# Screenshot image is not displaying in email attachment while using editable email notification plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying send an email with attachment as html report, using editable email plugin in Jenkins. I am using OS Linux(Ubuntu). I am able to sent the html report as an email attachment, but when I downloaded and open the attachment, the screen shot is broken inside the report.Seems like screenshot path is not taken.

The report is displaying properly with the screenshot in Jenkins using HTML Publisher plugin.The problem occurring while downloading the email attachment.

```
test-output/*
```

This is how i given the attachment path in the editable email plugin. So the html and png files are added as two different attachments and screenshot image showing as broken inside the report file.

seleniumDemo/test-output/index.html

seleniumDemo/test-output/embedded.png

The report is generated inside the workspace 'seleniumDemo' and this is how the report and screenshot files are generated.So how can get an email attachment with screenshot image.

```
**/index.html
```

when i given the attachment path like this, it taken html file only, not taking the screenshot image path. So can we generate a zip file of test-output folder and give its path to the attachment? or else how can we solve this?Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
test-output/*
```

this path will work!..Instead of downloading the index.html from the email, if we try Download all attachments options, then it will download as a zip file and we can see the perfect report with screenshot images after extracting the zip file.